# How to access a key in a stdclass

Tags: php

I have this situation:

```
object(stdClass)#203 (1) {
  ["1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (7) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "Device"
    ["name_first"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name_last"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name_display"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["gender"]=>
    string(11) "Unspecified"
    ["birthday"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I want to access either "user_id" or the ["1"], but this is of type stdclass so I can't treat it like an array. (Note: this is from `json_decode`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast it as an array:

```
$obj = (array) $obj;
$obj[1]["user_id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `json_decode()` when set to `TRUE` will automatically turn your results into an associative array:

```
$objs = json_decode($json, true);
echo $objs[1]["user_id"];
```

Comment: Nah this will complain about not having a "user_id" property.